# Proof of Slater's determinant for an n-particle fermionic system

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions

It is clear to me that the normalized determinant for a two-particle system gives the proper anti-symmetric wave function. How do I see clearly that this is the case for an n-particle fermionic system? Any elucidation would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Interchanging two rows of a determinant changes its sign, which is the desired property for a $N$-particle fermionic wave function. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598219/effect-of-elementary-row-operations-on-determinant) link will give you some more details about this property of determinants